# Determine whether any permutation of a string is a palindrome

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming

The task:

> Given a string, determine whether any permutation of it is a
>   palindrome.
>
> For example, "carrace" should return `true`, since it can be rearranged to
>   form "racecar", which is a palindrome. "daily" should return `false`, since
>   there's no rearrangement that can form a palindrome.

My solution:

```
const isPalindrome = str => {
  const letterOccurrences = str
  .split("")
  .reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x] = acc[x] ? acc[x] + 1 : 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  let numberOfOddOccurrences = 0;
  const isMaxOneOddNumberLetter = x => x % 2 === 0 || ++numberOfOddOccurrences <= 1;
  return Object.values(letterOccurrences).every(isMaxOneOddNumberLetter);
};

console.log(isPalindrome("carrace"));
```

Is it possible to write the function `isMaxOneOddNumberLetter` without mutation resp. side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to a previous question of yours, [Find the elements that appear only once](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216468/find-the-elements-that-appear-only-once/216502), and the same advice applies: use a Set and maintain a flag instead of a count.  If your Set ends up with size of zero or one, it's a palindrome.  Otherwise no.

```
const isPalindrome = s => s.split("").reduce( 
    (once, x) => (once.delete(x) || once.add(x), once),
    new Set() 
  ).size <= 1
```

If inputs are constrained to 26 letters, you can map each letter to a unique power of 2 and replace the set with a bit vector (aka an "integer"), using XOR to track which bits appear an odd number of times.  This may or may not be faster than a Set but it will certainly use less memory.  I'll leave the implementation as an exercise for the reader.