# Return whether a string is a palindrome if you can delete at most k elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, palindrome

The task:

> Given a string which we can delete at most k, return whether you can
>   make a palindrome.
>
> For example, given 'waterrfetawx' and a k of 2, you could delete f and
>   x to get 'waterretaw'.

The following solution is partially inspired by [@Oh My Goodness's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/216828/54442).

```
const s = "waterrfetawx";
const del = 2;

function palindromePossible(str, deleteAtMost) {
  const set = new Set();
  for (let i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    const char = str[i];
    void(set.delete(char) || set.add(char)); // <--is this good code?
  }

  let iStart = 0, iEnd = str.length - 1, possibleDeletion = 0;

  function isSame() {
    do {
      if (str[iStart] === str[iEnd]) {
        iStart++;
        iEnd--;
        return true;
      }
      if (++possibleDeletion > deleteAtMost) { return false; }
      if (set.has(str[iStart])) { iStart++; }
      if (set.has(str[iEnd])) { iEnd--; }
      if (iStart > iEnd) { return false; }
    } while(str[iStart] !== str[iEnd]);

    return true;
  }

  if (set.size <= deleteAtMost + 1) {
    for (let i = 0, len = Math.floor(str.length/2); i < len && iStart <= iEnd; i++) {
      if (!isSame()) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(palindromePossible(s, del));
```

Comment: I think you might have an off-by-1 error? `palindromePossible("waterrfetawx", 1)` returns `true`. AKA shouldn't `deleteAtMost + 1` just be `deleteAtMost`?

Comment: You can re-order it like this `waterfretawx` and then delete the `x`. `waterfretaw` can the be read forward and backwards @Shelby115

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware that re-ordering it was an option.

Comment: but good point. I will think of an algorithm that doesn't take re-ordering into consideration. @Shelby115

Comment: I think that allowing reordering is a bit of a cheat, especially if it is not mentioned in the task and the example lets you believe it isn't allowed. The given solutions don't work if it is not allowed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think you are right on this. I updated the code.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was more difficult, wasn't it? Now let's see if someone can improve on that.

Comment: Do we have this question in any of the OJ platforms like SPOJ, LeetCode, HackerRank, CodeForces etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a question embedded in the code:

> ```
> void(set.delete(char) || set.add(char)); // <--is this good code?
> ```

The [void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) "evaluates the given *expression* and then returns [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)</sup>. It doesn't appear that there is a need to have `undefined` be the final value of that expression because that expression doesn't get assigned or returned. The `void()` can be removed without changing the functionality of the code. I wouldn't say it is bad code, but unnecessary.

---

That `for` loop could be simplified:

> ```
> for (let i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
>   const char = str[i];
>   void(set.delete(char) || set.add(char)); // <--is this good code?
> }
> ```

using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
for (const char of str) {
  set.delete(char) || set.add(char);
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void</sub>